# Meu programa não está somando os dados que recebe. Programa em C

Tags: c

Eu preciso fazer um programa que:

- Receba o modelo do pc, o preço dele e exiba o maior valor, além da quantidade de computadores sem periféricos.
- Na função principal, receber a quantidade de periféricos.
- Uma função que receba como parâmetro a quantidade de periféricos, faça a soma dos  preços deles.
- exibir a quantidade de vendas sem periféricos adicionais e o valor da maior venda.

Entretanto, na hora de exibir o maior valor, o mesmo sai de forma errada.

Abaixo, o código realizado.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float pg_peri (int qtdper){
    float precoperi;


            printf ("Digite o valor do periferico:\n");
            scanf ("%f",&precoperi);
    return precoperi;

    }



int main (){
    float precomod, maior, pctot, pcperi, somaper;
    int cont, qtdperi1, codmod, vdperi, qtdmodelos, cc;
    somaper = 0;
    vdperi = 0;
    cont = 0;
    maior = 0;
    printf ("Digite quantos computadores deseja comprar\n");
    scanf ("%d", &qtdmodelos);
    while (cont < qtdmodelos){
            printf ("Digite o codigo do modelo desejado e seu preco\n");
            scanf ("%d%f", &codmod,&precomod);
            if (codmod == 0){
                            return 1;
            }
            printf ("Digite a quantidade de perifericos que você precisa\n");
            scanf ("%d",&qtdperi1);
            cc = 0;
                while (cc < qtdperi1){
                    pcperi = pg_peri(qtdperi1);
                    somaper = pcperi + somaper;
                    cc++;
        }
                            if (qtdperi1 == 0){
                                vdperi++;
            }

                            pctot = pcperi + precomod;
                                    if (maior < pctot ){
                                    maior = pctot;
            }


                cont++;

            }
            printf ("A quantidade de vendas sem peri \n%d e o maior eh de \n%.2f", vdperi, maior);
            return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Começo por dizer que deve dar relevância à indentação, pois é mais importante do que parece quando está a começar. Rapidamente acaba por achar o código mais facil de ler e organizado, e o mesmo para terceiros que queiram ler o seu código.

Quanto ao código faltaram duas coisas:

- Reiniciar o valor do `pctot` e `somaper` a cada passagem do `while`, para que seja calculado corretamente a cada pc:

  ```
  while (cont < qtdmodelos)
  {
      pctot = 0; // <-----
      somaper = 0; // <-----
      printf ("Digite o codigo do modelo desejado e seu preco\n");
      ....
  ```
- Aumentar o valor do pc com a soma de todos os periféricos em vez do valor do ultimo periférico :

  ```
  pctot = somaper + precomod; //em vez de pctot = pcperi + precomod;
  ```

O código completo e indentado ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float pg_peri (int qtdper) {
    float precoperi;
    printf ("Digite o valor do periferico:\n");
    scanf ("%f",&precoperi);
    return precoperi;
}

int main () {
    float precomod, maior, pctot, pcperi, somaper;
    int cont, qtdperi1, codmod, vdperi, qtdmodelos, cc;
    somaper = 0;
    vdperi = 0;
    cont = 0;
    maior = 0;
    printf ("Digite quantos computadores deseja comprar\n");
    scanf ("%d", &qtdmodelos);
    while (cont < qtdmodelos) {
        pctot = 0; // <------
        somaper = 0; // <-----
        printf ("Digite o codigo do modelo desejado e seu preco\n");
        scanf ("%d%f", &codmod,&precomod);
        if (codmod == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        printf ("Digite a quantidade de perifericos que você precisa\n");
        scanf ("%d",&qtdperi1);
        cc = 0;
        while (cc < qtdperi1) {
            pcperi = pg_peri(qtdperi1);
            somaper = pcperi + somaper;
            cc++;
        }
        if (qtdperi1 == 0) {
            vdperi++;
        }

        pctot = somaper + precomod;  // <-----
        if (maior < pctot) {
            maior = pctot;
        }

        cont++;
    }
    printf ("A quantidade de vendas sem peri \n%d e o maior eh de \n%.2f", vdperi, maior);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Realmente, percebo que meu código é muito mal formulado e isso atrapalha muito meu entendimento do mesmo.
Obrigado pelo auxílio, preciso entender melhor sobre esse tipo de repetição. Acerca do reset no while, toda vez que faço soma separada, devo colocar a variável nula nessa estrutura?

Comment: @MatheusCoelho Eu disse isso para ser algo que deve pensar em melhorar também. Pois muitas vezes quem está a iniciar acaba por achar que não tem relevância nenhuma, quando tem.